# How to mock Calendar.getInstance method using JMockit?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, jmockit

I am trying to mock `Calendar.getInstance()` method using JMockit. This is the first time I am mocking anything.

Below is my method which gives me the date of either recent `Monday` or recent `Thursday` in the format of `YYYYMMDD`.

Today is Sunday, so it should return date for Thursday in the format of `YYYYMMDD` so it will be - `2014027`

```
public static String getCorrectDate() {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    try {
        int dow = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        switch (dow) {
        case Calendar.THURSDAY:
        case Calendar.FRIDAY:
        case Calendar.SATURDAY:
        case Calendar.SUNDAY:
        while (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.THURSDAY) {
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        }
        break;
        case Calendar.MONDAY:
        case Calendar.TUESDAY:
        case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
        while (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.MONDAY) {
            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        }
        break;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // log error
    }

    return toDateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

So my question is how do I mock the `Calendar.getInstance` method using JMokcit so that I can easily junit `getCorrectDate` method?

I have never mocked it before so I am facing some problem?

Can anyone provide a simple example if possible on my example?

I am trying to do it like this but it is complaining me on `MockClass` as it is not able to resolve.. I have added the maven dependency of JMockit as well

```
@MockClass(realClass = Calendar.class) 
class CalendarMock {
 private int hour;
 private int day;
 private int minute;

 public CalendarMock(int day, int hour, int minute) {
  this.hour = hour;
  this.day = day;
  this.minute = minute;
 }

 @Mock
 public int get(int id) {
  if (id == Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) {
   return hour;
  }
  if (id == Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) {
   return day;
  }

  if (id == Calendar.MINUTE) {
   return minute;
  }
  return -1;
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't know about JMockIt, but PowerMock can mock system classes.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class CalendarTest {

    @Test
    public void testCalender() {

        new MockCalendar(1,2,3);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int day = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        Assert.assertEquals(day, 2);
    }

  public static class MockCalendar extends MockUp<Calendar> {
        private int hour;
        private int minute;
        private int day;

        public MockCalendar(int day, int hour, int minute) {
            this.hour = hour;
            this.minute = minute;
            this.day = day;
        }
        @Mock
        protected void $init() {}

        @Mock
        public static Calendar getInstance() {
            return new GregorianCalendar(1970,1,1);
        }

        @Mock
        public int get(int id) {
            if (id == Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) {
                return hour;
            }
            if (id == Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) {
                return day;
            }

            if (id == Calendar.MINUTE) {
                return minute;
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
 }

}
```

you can enhance the get logic to do stuff.

Comment: Returning a GreorgianCalendar madre the magic for me, thanks Russel ;)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try to mock a static method here, I would strongly recommend introducing a `Clock` interface along these lines:

```
public interface Clock {
    Date now(); // Or long, or Instant if you're using Joda Time
}
```

Then you can have a production implementation which uses `new Date()` or `System.currentTimeMillis`, and a test implementation where you can set "the current time". Pass your clock to the method, or make it an instance method and "configure" the instance (e.g. in the constructor) with the appropriate clock.

The `Clock` interface makes your code *much* simpler to test in my experience, without having to rely on relatively advanced mocking features for mocking static methods.

So your production code would become something like:

```
public static String getCorrectDate(Clock clock) {
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTimeZone(...); // Which time zone are you interested in?
    cal.setTime(clock.now()); // Or cal.setTimeInMillis(clock.now());

    // ... logic as before
}
```

Now you can test that with lots of different dates and times.

Comment: Thanks Jon. But how would I use this in my current code.. Can you provide a simple example for this?

Comment: @SSH: You would create an instance of `GregorianCalendar` (assuming you don't want to handle other calendar systems) and use `setTime` or `setTimeInMillis` to populate it with the current date/time. You should also consider which time zone you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete test class (minus imports) for the `getCorrectDate()` method, using the two mocking APIs available in JMockit 1.6:

```
public class DateAdjustmentTest
{
    final int year = 2014;
    final int month = Calendar.MARCH;
    final Calendar[] datesOnDifferentWeekdays = {
        new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 2), // a sunday
        new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 3), // a monday
        new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 4), // a tuesday
        new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 5), // a wednesday
        new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 6), // a thursday
        new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 7), // a friday
        new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 8), // a saturday
    };

    @Test
    public void getAdjustedDateAccordingToWeekday_usingExpectationsAPI()
    {
        new NonStrictExpectations(Calendar.class) {{
            // Each consecutive call to this method will return the next date.
            // Calls to other Calendar methods will not be mocked.
            Calendar.getInstance(); result = datesOnDifferentWeekdays;
        }};

        assertEachDayOfWeekGetsCorrectlyAdjusted();
    }

    void assertEachDayOfWeekGetsCorrectlyAdjusted()
    {
        String thursdayOfPreviousWeek = "27/02/2014";
        assertEquals(thursdayOfPreviousWeek, getCorrectDate());

        String mondayOfSameWeek = "03/03/2014";
        assertEquals(mondayOfSameWeek, getCorrectDate());
        assertEquals(mondayOfSameWeek, getCorrectDate());
        assertEquals(mondayOfSameWeek, getCorrectDate());

        String thursdayOfSameWeek = "06/03/2014";
        assertEquals(thursdayOfSameWeek, getCorrectDate());
        assertEquals(thursdayOfSameWeek, getCorrectDate());
        assertEquals(thursdayOfSameWeek, getCorrectDate());
    }

    @Test
    public void getAdjustedDateAccordingToWeekday_usingMockUpAPI()
    {
        new MockUp<Calendar>() {
            @Mock
            Calendar getInstance(Invocation inv)
            {
                return datesOnDifferentWeekdays[inv.getInvocationIndex()];
            }
        };

        assertEachDayOfWeekGetsCorrectlyAdjusted();
    }
}
```

I would say both tests are quite simple, without having to change the original production code.

Comment: Can we do it with `Expectations(Calender.class)`? And why we are passing `Calendar.class` to NonStrictExpectations, Can we do it with NonStrictExpectations, It will partially mock the class(Which I think so)? Please may you explain thease doubts to me. I am using JMockit 1.7. Thank you

Comment: Yes, `Expectations(Calendar.class)` will work the same, except that you'll have *strict* expectations, so keep that in mind. Both tests above *partially* mock the `Calendar` class, since we only want to make `getInstance()` return (unmocked) calendar objects. For more information and examples, please refer to the [online documentation](http://jmockit.github.io/tutorial.html).